# Auto assign data to property in class for java 8

Tags: java

i have a class call Car

```
class Car {

  public String model;
  public String make;
  public int year;
  public String color;
  public boolean have_trunk;
  public int door_count; // automatic if no in file

  //etc... i have lot 
}
```

i have this field but when one is no there i want to assign it automatic.

my controller is

```
public String post(@RequestBody @Valid Car car) {
  // code here
  // at this point if the make is no here i want 
}
```

all data is mysql, for make and model and year and doors and all

my example:
like if have:

> {model:Aspire,year:1999, rest of data no model}

> model: Aspire -- i want to populate Make with Ford, door_count with 5, have_trunk = true

or

> {model:Imperial,year:1999, rest of data no model}

> model: Imperial -- i want to populate Make with Chrysler

etc..

so in service data i can do:

```
System.out.println(car);
```

then it have

```
{car:{model:Aspire,make:Ford, door_count: 5, have_trunk: true, rest of data }}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what the issue is--if you have a `Car` and it's missing data use the data you *do* have to fill in whatever missing data you want, however you want.

Comment: so i import excel data and not all data present also there other data and i want fill automatic like how many door or have trunk

Comment: i update ticket

Comment: Ok. What's the specific issue?

Comment: What is your "database"? I.e. if you get model "Aspire", you need to look in a "database" to find that "Aspire" is a Ford, with 5 doors and a trunk. It doesn't have to be an actual database, just some place to lookup "Aspire" and get "Ford"; lookup "Imperial" and get "Chrysler". Etc.

Comment: @Kevin yes i have a database with all data like you mention and more i use mysql

Comment: @DaveNewton how to automatic data if data is not in the json?

Comment: Perhaps if you would explain what the use case is it would help? What application use case are you trying to solve exactly? Are you searching existing `Car`s by example and want to return the possible matches?

Comment: i import excel data and not all data present also there other data and i want fill automatic like how many door or have trunk

Comment: With your database: if you get the model "Aspire", you open the mysql database, query for "Aspire" to fetch make, door_count, have_trunk, and so on. Then populate your structure fields from the results of your database query.

Comment: @Kevin how to execute ?

Comment: This is starting to sound like you want someone to write the code for you. I'm sure that I and others would be happy to give you feedback on your program, but you have to write and post it.

Comment: @Kevin no i just dont understsand java and how to